# How to check if zip file is accessible?

Tags: vba, excel, zip, corruption

I have an Excel table with lots of PC names. Each PC should have a backup stored on the server in .zip files that are auto generated.

When I run my code, it checks the PC names to check if they have a backup.

The backup process isn't perfect so there might be a problem to be resolved manually after the problem is detected.

One of the problems that I can not detect is if the backup process doesn't finish and the .zip file gets corrupted.

I want to write another function to detect corrupted .zip files that can not be opened.

Here is the code:

```
Sub check_for_all_backups()

Dim c As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim Backup As String

For j = 1 To Worksheets.Count
Set rng = Sheets(j).UsedRange.Cells

For Each c In rng
    If ispcname(Left(c, 7)) = True And Right(c, 1) = "$" Then

    Dim i
    i = 1

    Backup = Left(c, 7)
    c.Interior.ColorIndex = "0"

    File = Dir(BU_Folder_Dir)
    Do While File <> ""

        isbig = True '|
        Dim FSO
        Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") '|

        myBool = False
        isnew = False
        Backup = Right(Backup, 6)

            If InStr(File, Backup) > 0 Then

                myBool = True
                cfile = Dir(BU_Folder_Dir & Left(c, 7) & "*")

                Do While cfile <> ""
                    ReDim arr(i)
                    arr(i) = FileDateTime(BU_Folder_Dir & cfile)

                    ReDim Size(i)    '|
                    Size(i) = BU_Folder_Dir & cfile

                    fsize = FSO.getfile(Size(i)).Size / 1024 / 1024 'MB
                    If fsize <= 2048 Then 'is file smaller than 2 GB ?
                        isbig = False
                    End If  '|


                    If Now - arr(i) < 30 Then
                        isnew = True
                    End If

                    i = i + 1
                    cfile = Dir()
                Loop

                If isbig = True Then          '|
                    If c.Comment Is Nothing Then
                        c.AddComment ("reduce _mit size." & vbCrLf & ".zip over 2GB & (" & fsize & ")")
                    End If
                ElseIf isbig = False Then
                    If Not c.Comment Is Nothing Then
                        c.ClearComments
                    End If
                End If                        '|

                If isnew = False Then
                    c.Interior.ColorIndex = "6"
                ElseIf isnew = True Then
                    c.Interior.ColorIndex = "35"
                End If
                Exit Do

            End If
        File = Dir()
    Loop


        If Not myBool Then
            c.Interior.ColorIndex = "22"
        End If

    End If
Next c

Next j

Call backup_statistics

End Sub
```

The Excel table has more purposes so the "$" sign is only used to make a difference between PC names and backup names in other subs/functions. PC names are identified with another function called `ispcname`. The name of the backup .zip file always contains the PC name.

The script has only read access to the folder and zip files.

There are around ~1000 zip files to be checked. Their size can reach up to 2 GB, so I need some method that can check if the files are accessible without too much processing.

Comment: One option would be to try unzipping it or checking the filenames in the ZIP per [this by Ron de Bruin](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s7/win002.htm).  Or see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25755264/2877364).

Comment: Thank you for the information, I will start experimenting with these methods. I have updated my question with additional information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So although answered in the comments, giving some code if someone lands on this question page ...

OK, so the references in the comments either extract the files from the zip which you don't want (it will takes absolutely ages and why when you only need to check contents?)  Or they do not explicitly type their variable making the code quite mysterious to those not familiar with the libraries.  Or, they have superfluous throw dialog boxes etc.

Here is an explicitly typed function which returns a list of files from the zip then you can check contents with the Dictionary's Exist method.

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestCheckZipFileContents()

    Dim dic As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set dic = CheckZipFileContents("C:\Users\Bob\Downloads\zipped.zip")
    Debug.Print VBA.Join(dic.Keys, vbNewLine)
    Stop
End Sub

Function CheckZipFileContents(ByVal sZipFile As String) As Scripting.Dictionary

    '* Tools->References  Microsoft Scripting Runtime                   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\scrrun.dll
    '* Tools->References  Microsoft Shell Controls and Automation       C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shell32.dll

    Dim FSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Set FSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    If FSO.FileExists(sZipFile) Then

        Dim oShell As Shell32.Shell
        Set oShell = New Shell32.Shell

        Dim oFolder As Shell32.Folder

        '* next line is the magic line that opens the zip
        '* if there is corruption it would start failing here
        Set oFolder = oShell.Namespace(sZipFile)

        Dim oFolderItems As Shell32.FolderItems
        Set oFolderItems = oFolder.Items

        Debug.Print oFolderItems.Count

        Dim dicContents As Scripting.Dictionary
        Set dicContents = New Scripting.Dictionary

        Dim oFolderItemLoop As Shell32.FolderItem
        For Each oFolderItemLoop In oFolderItems
            dicContents.Add oFolderItemLoop, 0
        Next oFolderItemLoop

        Set oFolderItemLoop = Nothing
        Set oFolderItems = Nothing
        Set oFolder = Nothing
        Set oShell = Nothing

        Set CheckZipFileContents = dicContents


    End If

End Function
```

Comment: Tested it and I get the error `user-defined type not defined`

Comment: on the function: `Function CheckZipFileContents(ByVal sZipFile As String) As Scripting.Dictionary`

Comment: You need to go Tools->References  then check "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" and "Microsoft Shell Controls and Automation"

Comment: Sorry, I have missed that somehow. This is a very nice script, I like it. I will start implementing it and check if it can handle ~1000 zip files. One thing you should modify is to replace the `Stop` with `End` because it won't run.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I do that so  user can see the variables in the Locals window, its a habit and you're right for production code should be removed.

Comment: I got it tested in a local test folder. Runs trough 1700 files (2.40 GB) in around 5-10 seconds. It is just what I needed! Thank you!