# How to get list of files in a compressed/zipped folder?

Tags: excel, vba

Normally I would do a simple ctrl + A, right click, and copy as path to get file names but I don't think i can within a zipped folder. Below is the VBA code I'm trying to run, but I get a "Run Time Error '76': Path not found" message. is there any way to accomplish what i'm trying to do?

```vb
Sub LoopThroughFiles()

    Dim strPathToSearch
    Dim oFSO As Object
    Dim oFolder As Object
    Dim oFile As Object
    Dim i As Integer
    
    strPathToSearch = Range("A2").Value
    'For Testing
    'MsgBox strPathToSearch
    
    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(strPathToSearch)
    
    i = 4
    'For Testing
    'MsgBox (i)
    
    
    For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
    
        If oFile.Type = "Adobe Acrobat Document" Or oFile.Type = "Text Document" Then
            Cells(i, 1) = oFile.ParentFolder
            Cells(i, 2) = oFile.Name
            Cells(i, 3) = oFile.Type
            Cells(i, 4) = oFile.DateCreated
            Cells(i, 5) = oFile.DateLastModified
        
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next oFile
End Sub
```

Comment: [This may be useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65851055/list-contents-of-a-ziptar-file-using-vba)

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25755264/vba-read-a-zip-file/25757993#25757993